# Price not showing on product page

Tags: magento-1.8, product, price, catalog

I adding my product to bx slider...
i calling data from catalog model ....
how can i get price on slider...
my magento code is ..

```
    <?php 
     $category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
    $category->load(6);
    $_products  = $category->getProductCollection();

    $_products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $_products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
    $_products->addFieldToFilter(array(array('attribute'=>'visibility', 'neq'=>"1" )));

    $_products->getSelect()->limit(30);
      ?>

my slider html..
----------------

<div class="sale_slide_women">
                <?php $i=0; foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): $i++; ?>
                    <div class="slide <?php if(($i == 4 && $_products->getSize() < 5) || ($i == $_products->getPageSize())) echo 'last'?>">
                        <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(210) ?>" width="210" height="210" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" /></a>
                        <div class="new-description text-center">
                            <div class="labels-container"><?php include('view/labels.phtml'); ?></div>
                            <h3><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><?php echo Mage::helper('core/string')->truncate($this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()), $length = 30, $etc = '...', $remainder = '', $breakWords = true); ?></a></h3>
                            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

`<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>` is not work because did not call price block

you need to call price block

remove this code and below
try this

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_price')
            ->setTemplate('catalog/product/price.phtml')
            ->setProduct($_product)
            ->setDisplayMinimalPrice(true)
            ->setIdSuffix($idSuffix='amit')
            ->toHtml(); ?>
```

You need set price.phtml  and check you price.phtml is your price phtml

Answer (score 1):

The code that you're using to show price:

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
```

Is for default taking template from file app/design/frontend/your_template/your_template/catalog/product/price.html

For testing purposes try to replace upper code with this:

```
<?php echo $_product->getPrice(); ?>
```

And see if price is displayed. If yes then the template file is your reason for not displaying price and we should try to look in there.